# url amigaveis categoria subcategoria

Tags: htaccess

Com a categoria funciona mais como eu coloco a subcategoria também?

```
produtos/nome-categoria/nome-subcategoria


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
    #aqui criamos uma condição para que os arquivos sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #aqui criamos uma condição para que diretórios sejam ignorados nas regras abaixo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #aqui definimos onde começa a base das regras

    #fix rules
    RewriteRule ^pagina-inicial/?$ index.php [NC,L]
        #RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1&nome_categoria=$2 [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ subcategorias.php?id_subcategoria=$1&nome_categoria=$2 [NC,L]
        </IfModule>
```

Comment: Essa regra funciona  para as duas? produtos/nome-categoria e produtos/nome-categoria/nome-subcategoria

Answer (score 0):

Se você possui apenas um Script de busca nas tabelas, remova as regras anteriores e deixe apenas esta:

```
RewriteRule ^produtos/categoria/(.*)/subcategoria/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1&id_subcategoria=$2 [NC,L]
```

Exemplo de chamada da url:

```
produtos/categoria/id-da-categoria/subcategoria/id-da-subcategoria
```

Se você possui dois Scripts de busca, um de categoria e outro de subcategoria, deixe estas duas regras:

```
RewriteRule ^produtos/categoria/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^produtos/subcategoria/(.*)$ subcategorias.php?id_subcategoria=$1 [NC,L]
```

Exemplo de chamada da url por categoria:

```
produtos/categoria/id-da-categoria
```

Exemplo de chamada da url por subcategoria:

```
produtos/subcategoria/id-da-subcategoria
```

Comment: deu certoo valeuu

Comment: cara fiz assim e nao funcionou 

RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)/(.*)$ subcategorias.php?id_categoria=$1&id_subcategoria=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: produtos/nome-categoria funciona

produtos/nome-categoria/sub-categoria não funciona

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard você tem que eliminar as regras anteriores e deixar somente esta da resposta. A mesma já é para categorias e subcategorias.

Comment: Você tem dois scritps de busca é isso mesmo? "categorias.php" e "subcategorias.php" ?

Comment: sim isso mesmo

produtos/id-da-categoria 
produtos/id-da-categoria/id-da-subcategoria

Comment: Fiz uma nova edição na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

assim funciona

categorias/nome-categoria

subcategorias/nome-categoria/nome-subcategorias

```
RewriteRule ^categorias/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^subcategorias/(.*)/(.*)$ subcategorias.php?id_categoria=$1&id_subcategoria=$2 [NC,L]
```

Mais não teria como ficar assim?

```
produtos/nome-categoria
ptosutos/nome-categoria/nome-subcategorias
```

Fiz assim e não funcionou

```
RewriteRule ^categorias/(.*)$ categorias.php?id_categoria=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^subcategorias/(.*)/(.*)$ subcategorias.php?id_categoria=$1&id_subcategoria=$2 [NC,L]
```